# i faced problem in baseclass and derived class

Tags: class, oop, inheritance

I faced some problem in topic inheritence in this i make a Baseclass a "Animal" and its subClass
"Dog" but after makin object of Dog i print no of legs ,eyes ,sound but after the code run there is written eyes=0;legs=0;& sound=null.
Below is my code..

```
 class Animal{
    int legs;
    int eyes;
    public void setEyes(int i){
        i=eyes;
        return;
    }
    public int getEyes(){
       return eyes;
    }
    public void setLegs(int i){
        i=legs;
        return;
    }
    public int getLegs(){
       return legs;
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal{
    String sound;
    public void setSound(String i){
        i=sound;
        return;
    }
    public String getSound(){
       return sound;
    }

}
public class practice_oops{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog D=new Dog();
        D.setEyes(2);
        D.setLegs(4);
        D.setSound("bark");
        System.out.println(D.getEyes());
        System.out.println(D.getLegs());
        System.out.println(D.getSound());
    }
}
```

Comment: You always set the global variable to the local variable. It must be the global to local variable( sound=i).

Answer (score 0):

You should set
`eyes=i`,
`legs=i`,
`sound=i`
in the
`setEyes()`,
`setLegs()`,
`setSound()`
functions respectively.